# Is there a way to force Windows to recognize a network folder as a local drive, for the purposes of being able to search it with Everything?

Tags: windows-xp, search, network-shares, everything

I just started using the file search program Everything at work to search through documentation on our shared drives. This is after disappointments with Google Desktop and Windows Search.

I love the speed of Everything, but I wish it were able to index other shared folders. My makeshift solution was to somehow force Windows to recognize the necessary shared folders as local drives, then add them to the index list.

I have also considered using SyncToy, but this requires downloading all data to my drive, which could be terabytes of information - obviously not a good idea on a small company network.

What would be the best solution here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Everything FAQ has a question about this:

http://www.voidtools.com/faq.php#Can__Everything__index_a_mapped_network_drive

Comment: Yeah - I think I had seen this when I was searching through the FAQ at one point, but since I would need the admin to put Everything on the host server, it's not really an option for me. I was hoping more along the lines of "tricking" Windows into thinking a network drive is actually local. C'mon Super Users.

Comment: If you are a small company, that shouldn't be hard.  I'll post a tricky idea too, and see how many down votes it gets!

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping the folder as a drive.  Right-click on "My Computer", select Map Drive, and follow the wizzard.  Then you have a drive letter assigned to the folder, and you can then tell the search to look in "My Computer" and it'll include the network drive you mapped as well as the local drives.

Comment: Thanks, but this is the current setup and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To be tricky... you could:

- xcopy L:*.*  C:\ /t /e
  -- Copies the subdirectory structure (that is, the tree) only, not files. To copy empty directories, you must include the /e command-line option.  (note: robocopy may also work)

Since all the filenames and structure are now local, Everything should work.  You would have to do the xcopy as a batch job on a schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Server editions of Windows has search indexing.  You won't find this feature on the consumer side.